# Need to calculate number of rows in sql on the basis of modify date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

What I'm trying to do is to calculate the number of rows of the table which updated 2 days means suppose I have some data like this:

```
ID  Name    Department   DateTime                     ModifyDate
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   XXXXX   IT           2013-09-10 09:53:01.000      2013-09-10 09:55:01.000
2   YYYYY   Tech         2013-09-09 10:00:00.000      2013-09-10 12:00:00.000
3   WWWW    IT           2013-09-09 08:09:00.000      2013-09-10 09:09:00.000
```

Now there are two rows which modify on 10 sep

I want a query which will give me the count of no. of row modify per day.

My desired out will be like this

```
No. of column
    2
```

Comment: So what is your desired result and have you tried something?

Comment: i am not able to create a query for this i create a query which will give the no. of columns bt for all date i want to check modify record on daily basis

Comment: i edit my question you getmy desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select count(ID) from TableName where  ModifyDate>=@Today and ModifyDate<@NextDay", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Today",  DateTime.Today  ));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Nextday", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) ));

                    int count = 0;
                    int.TryParse( command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()   , out count);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Seriously?! @MichaelB has answered your original question, has this not solved your problem? If it has you should mark his answer as correct.

Comment: i didn't login after that answer now i use that answer and it work thanks make

Answer (score 1):

```
select Distinct Count(ID) from Table where ModifyDate between '2013-09-10' and '2013-09-11'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TableX WHERE ModifyDate BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate;
```

Pass your start and end dates to the appropriate variables

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use something like

```
SELECT count(ID) 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY CAST(ModifyDate AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as [No. of column] from Table1
where CAST(ModifyDate as Date) = 'Sep 10, 2013'
```

Replace 'Sep 10, 2013' with GetDate() if you want to filter on the current date.

Comment: Are you using a SQLDataSource in ASP.NET?  Maybe you could modify its SelectCommand property, or just create a view using the SQL above on the database and create a new SQLDataSource based on that.

Comment: i want only present date row no. not all date number

Comment: if i put date then ur query work but if i put getdate() it give me 0 column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,ModifiedDate) AS DATE, count(ID) AS TotalUpdated
FROM TableName
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,ModifiedDate)
```

Try this query.